# How to customize the horizontal rule which follows the section heading?

Tags: sectioning, rules

I am preparing my resume and want to customize the section headings.

I want a *horizontal rule **to fill** the empty space (linewidth)* after the section heading.

Following is what I have been able to do till now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xhfill}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{\textcolor{gray}{\rule{5mm}{3mm}} #1 \xhrulefill{gray}{3mm}}

\begin{document}

{\noindent\Huge{John Doe}}
\section{Education}

\end{document}
```

The above code gives me the following output:
[image]

However, I want to have a color gradient on the right side like this:
[image]

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by @muzimuzhiZ's answer, using a box to derive the length of the title. It doesn't work at all for multi-line titles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox\MyBox
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{%
  \tikz\fill[black](0,0) rectangle (5mm,3mm);%
  \sbox\MyBox{\ #1\ }\usebox\MyBox%
  \tikz\fill[left color=black, right color=black!20] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth-5mm-\the\wd\MyBox, 3mm);%
}

\begin{document}
{\noindent\Huge{John Doe}}
\section{Education}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test of longer section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stefan, your solution works very well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

- Use `\linegoal` from `linegoal` package to get the remaining width of current line.
- Use `tikz` package to fill a rectangle with shading (horizontal color gradient).
  `xhfill` uses `\leader` to fill the remaining line with narrow colored rules, hence is not capable of applying a shading.
- `\linegoal` will write position info to aux file, hence cannot be used directly in a `tikz` coordinate. Therefore its expanded value is stored in a temp length `\mylinegoal`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\newlength\mylinegoal

\makeatletter
\newcommand\setlinegoal{%
  \setlength\mylinegoal{\linegoal}%
  % draw only when \linegoal expands to the remaining length
  \ifdim\mylinegoal=\linewidth
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{%
  \textcolor{gray}{\rule{5mm}{3mm}} #1 %
  \setlinegoal{%
    \tikz\fill[left color=gray, right color=black!20] 
      (0,0) rectangle (\mylinegoal, 3mm);%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

{\noindent\Huge{John Doe}}
\section{Education}

\section{Test loooong loooong loooong loooong loooong loooong loooong title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, there is a potential bug. For example, if I add another section, say for work experience, I get the the rectangle below the heading, and not besides it.

Comment: @TRK Answer improved.

Comment: Yes, your answer works now :)